"You don't have any Pixels." message during Facebook Login for Business
I have a Business Account A, where I have a Dataset setup (which is the what a Pixel is now called) and that Pixel is assigned as an asset to Business Account A's Ad Account.
I have an app under Business Account B which is using Facebook Business Login with scopes ad_management, pages_read_engagement and pages_show_list.
When I try to Facebook Login using Account B's client_id app, and enter credentials for a user which owns Business Account A, I keep seeing the message on the Pixel select screen:
"You don't have any Pixels. To continue, you'll need to create a Pixel using a business portfolio and come back here."
Why is this not seeing the Pixel? The Pixel is collecting data correctly but it doesn't show up during the "connect" process when someone from Business Account A wants to use my service.

Did you ever figure this out? Having this exact issue. They have this page that walks through adding a Pixel in the Events Manager.. but after adding it, it's not seeming to get pulled in after clicking the "refresh" button when the user is signing in to their Facebook account to enable the API.

I needed advanced access to view other people's business information. Unless they have a role in the app you need advanced access.
